# IE not reading media query

Tags: css, internet-explorer, responsive-design, media-queries

Does anyone know the proper use of media queries for IE? I tried using media queries in my page and in my call to the css file but i still do not see the media query being referenced.

```
@media only screen and (min-width : 768px) and (max-width : 1024px) {
    #logoBig{
        display:none;
    }

    #logoSmall{
        display:block !important;

    }

    .logo{
        width:200px !important;
    }

    .fields{
        margin: 32px 0 0 0px;
        width:62% !important;
    }
    ul li .submenu{
        display:none;
    }
    ul li:hover .submenu{
        display:block;
    }
```

Where is the best place to put this media query and what guidelines do i need to follow?

IE 11 and here is my meta tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Comment: Are you using IE8? if so, it will not work. What version of IE are you using?

Comment: This media query works in Internet Explorer 11. I confirmed by creating [a small repro fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g6v9mcww/).

Comment: Also, we need your meta tag in your html showing your viewport info.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a closing bracket at the end of your query

```
@media only screen and (min-width : 768px) and (max-width : 1024px) {
    #logoBig{
        display:none;
    }

    #logoSmall{
        display:block !important;

    }

    .logo{
        width:200px !important;
    }

    .fields{
        margin: 32px 0 0 0px;
        width:62% !important;
    }
    ul li .submenu{
        display:none;
    }
    ul li:hover .submenu{
        display:block;
    }
}
```

but this would be an issue with all browsers, please update your html with your div's if this syntax error is not your issue.